# javascript regular expression select html element with class="product" from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, regular-language

lets say i use jquery.get to retrive a website to string and how am i gonna select the whole table with class=product from it? $() seem cant work on string ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for this, like this:

```
$("#elementToLoadIn").load("myPage.htm .product");
```

The format is `"url selector"` (note the space there).

The `$.get` alternative is:

```
$.get("myPage.htm", function(data) {
   $("#elementToLoadIn").html($(".product", data));
});
```